# Finding the location of a function programmatically

Tags: php, function

I am making amendments to a website built by another who used quite literally 1000's of files which are called at any point (i assume it was his attempt at implementing DRY), and I am searching for a specific function. Now usually, I would download the entire project (via FTP), import it into my favorite IDE (netbeans) and perform a search, however I am limited because the only way to access the files is individually through an antiquated hosting control panel that has no search functionality or mass download capability.

So, to try to make my job easier, is there any way to perform a lookup details on a function at runtime, such as its file, and what line its on?

The server that the site is running on has xdebug installed (I know, weird for a production server, but I'm not complaining if it can help).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks!  I had literally no idea what that might have been a typo for ;)

Comment: The first thing I'd do is upload some code to manage the files a bit better - you don't even need to write it yourself - there's lots of free tools available.

Comment: @symcbean I was gonna upload a script to rar the entire file tree, then download that as one, but this is something I have been wondering about for a while, and this provided a perfectly valid excuse to ask a question on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ReflectionFunction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) class. With the PHP reflection classes you can get meta information about PHP functions and classes. For your problem, you could do:

```
$function = new ReflectionFunction('function_name');
// $function->getFileName() returns the filename where is defined.
// $function->getStartLine() returns in which line is defined.
```

And so on. In the link above you get a list of all the methods available.

Comment: excellent, i was just searching on the reflection classes, but google was only coming up with "changing a function's code"

Comment: Thats why StackOverflow is better than Google :) If it works for you, don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: It is isn't it. Would have liked to but the silly system doesn't let you accept an answer for 15 minutes...